# Dropdown no cierra al hacer click en item

Tags: html

Buenos dias,
Tengo un problema con un dropdown.
Al hacer click en algun elemento no lo cierra.

```
                        <div class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button" id="btn1"  onclick="action()">Tipo de Teléfono <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="listfiber">
                                                <li><a href="#" value="Fijo" onclick="fijo1()">Fijo</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" value="Celular" onclick="cel1()">Celular</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
```

Tienen idea que puede ser?

Gracias.

Comment: y estas importando bien , los archivos js que necesitas??

Comment: Es mejor si puedes replicar lo que estas programando en un JsFiddle para poder ayudarte mejor, así podemos analizar de mejor manera donde esta tu problema.

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder ayudarte mejor, sube el código a un snipet para poder ayudarte mejor. Si te sirve te dejo un ejemplo de dropdown.

```js
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Display
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Expand All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Collapse All</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">Select All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="separated link">Clear All</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: **Esto no responde a la pregunta realizada por el OP**, esto es un ejemplo. Revisa [answer].